# Remove google-code-prettify border on code

Tags: css, pre, google-code-prettify

I want to remove the border on code while using `google-code-prettify`. I tried the following but got no result.

```
pre.prettyprint {
    border: none;
}
```

I also tried to remove borders on all `pre` tags, same no result.

```
pre {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to tell the browser which set of style instructions it should listen to. 
The `!important` property should tell te browser you you want your css to take precedent.

```css
pre.prettyprint {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This worked!  See here:  http://www.ncssm.edu/~morrison/currentClasses/402/Aug/testPrettify.php